# Add and Replace Jobs in Crontab

Tags: cron

EDIT: **This should be done in a script, not opening or editing via** `crontab -e`

I have a list of cron jobs that already exists, below are some of them

```
*/30 * * * * /path/to/script.sh
0 12 * * * /path/to/script_2.sh
* * * * /path/to/script_3.sh
```

Scenario:

1. `script_2.sh` is not found on some of the servers.
2. Need to add `>/dev/null 2>&1` to all of this script

How can I do in Linux script to search for `script_2.sh` if that is already present in the crontab? If it is present in the crontab, `>/dev/null 2>&1` should be appended. If it doesn't exist, it should be added to the jobs.

Comment: You just need to add a basic `sed` command to other commands from the linked answer. Like `sed 's!\.sh$!& \&>/dev/null 2>\&1!' file`

Comment: @GillesQuénot sorry I am new to linux script